# transfer data between columns Illegal mix of collations error

Tags: mysql, collation, transfer

I have been trying different ways to transfer data between tables/column based on the matched information. I've tried several options here on StackOverflow and if I try COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci; the DB hangs and I need to restart. If I don't use COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci; I get an error message.

Here is an example of the table structure: as You can see, I need to update `User` with data from `geo_city` based on the match between .city_title and .city.

```
geo DB

city_id | State_id | country_id | City_title 
--------------------------------------------
1234    :  567     :  890       :   New york
4321    :  765     :  098       :   Atlanta

............................................

User DB

city_id | State_id | country_id | city 
-------------------------------------------
0       : 0        : 0          : New york
0       : 0        : 0          : Atlanta


City is (utf8_general_ci)
city_title is (utf8_unicode_ci)
```

MySQL is throwing the following error:

```
MySQL said: Documentation
#1267 - Illegal mix of collations (utf8_general_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_unicode_ci,IMPLICIT) for operation '='
```

Here is code I was using:

```
UPDATE
    user,
    geo_city
SET
    user.city_id = geo_city.city_id
WHERE
    user.city = geo_city.city_title
```

*Update: I have set both tables to utf8_unicode_ci. I no longer get the error message. The only problem now is, MySQL Hangs and I get timeout. I've updated max execution time but it still gets 504.

Comment: 1) there is no question 2) there is no code 3) there is a contradiction: the titke nentions an error, then in the question itself you claim there is no error

Comment: I've edited the post. I'm totally new to MySql. Google has been good to me up to this point. How do I fix this? Thanks.

Comment: Incidentally, and confusingly, MySQL's implementation of UTF8 is called utf8mb4

Comment: You need to check the error logs why the collate crashes mysql. You could aldo try to permanently align the 2 fields' collation.

Comment: @Shadow: I've set both tables to utf8_unicode_ci

Comment: You need to convert one the existing fields' collation to the other field's collation. Setting it on table level does not help.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for both tables.  We need to see the extent of the issue, not just this _one_ symptom.